# MyISAM table dropped accidentally, I lost 1 month data, and my host has no backup

Tags: mysql, myisam, recovery

I accidentally deleted myisam table and created new one, and lost my data, I have no backup, is there any way to get that table or its data back? Please help!

I have tried to get backup from host, but they said they have no backup either.

Comment: If there is no backup where would you get the data from?

Answer (score 0):

You can try repair command.

```
repair table 'table_name';
```

Comment: but i imported other data, i lost 1 month data though

Comment: Then did you turn on mysql binary log feature?

Comment: i used drop table to drop that table but it was accidently, i didn't notice the database actually .

Comment: Then there isn`t no method. 
I hope you may find it from somewhere